# Why should Go’s http.Client instances be reused?

Tags: http, go, client, transport

The Go documentation [says](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Client)

> The Client's Transport typically has internal state (cached TCP connections), so Clients should be reused instead of created as needed. Clients are safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines.

Why does Client reuse help with preserving the Transport’s internal state, given that I can instantiate a transport and pass it to single-use Client instances like this:

```go
client := &http.Client{Transport: transport}
```

Comment: Because the documentation says so. The problem is that a lot of people think a net/http.Client is a one-shot thing to make one HTTP request. But of course the main state to be reused (besides the cookie Jar) is in Transport, so if you want you can reuse your Transport and create a new http.Client from that Transport but that is totally unneeded as you also could reuse the Client. So reuse the client. The documentation is correct here.

Comment: The recommendation to reuse Client may be valid, but you seem to confirm that the rationale for this in the documentation is not valid. Note that even instantiating a new Client without arguments reuses the DefaultTransport.

Comment: The package authors designed clients to be reusable. The documentation recommends that we use that feature.

Comment: The documentation states "The Client's _Transport_ typically has internal state (cached TCP connections), so Clients should be reused". This is to ensure users not familiar with the implementation are reusing a `Transport`, which is normally interfaced via a `Client`, by transitively referencing the same rule documented in the `Transport`: _"Transports should be reused instead of created as needed"_. If you understand all this, and know when it's appropriate to use a new `Client`, then that first "_should_" doesn't apply.

Comment: But the transport is automatically reused if new clients are created. In contrast, transports are not reused in only one scenario: You generate new clients and endow every one of them explicitly with different Transport instances. Am I correct that this scenario is the one the docs want to avoid with their recommendation?

Comment: I'm not sure what the argument is here. The documentation says "should", to help new users avoid the not uncommon misconception that one needs to create new clients and/or transports for concurrent use. Yes, this could all be spelled out in more detail, but at the point one understands that detail it's obvious what "should" be done anyway. The [`Client`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Client) struct is very simple. It's easy to see if you need a new one, and if you don't, creating multiple clients is just asking for bugs later if you ever set any of those fields explicitly

Comment: Thank you, I find this helpful. I still think the docs are confusing here: Instead of giving client-level state like cookie jar as the rationale for reusing clients, it only mentions Transport-level state. And even more, the problematic Transport scenario is very specific.  Anyway, I now know what to watch out with. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the problematic `Transport` scenario is very specific, but that is probably also the most common reason new users might make a new `Client`. I've seen it countless times where a different timeout or `tls.Config` is needed, and the user creates the new `Client` and `Transport` inline, then leaks idle connections.

Answer (score 3):

> Why should Go’s http.Client instances be reused?

There are many reasons. The most universal one is to allow reusing existing HTTP connections.  If you use a new `http.Client` instance for every request, you can never take advantage of existing HTTP connections, which will result in more overhead and slower performance for most common uses.

Another common reason would be to use a cookie jar, if you're calling an HTTP server that uses cookies.

Comment: I doubt that existing HTTP connections are not used, as they are managed on the Transport level.

Comment: The transport is part of the client. Your doubt doesn't make any sense.

Comment: No, the Client only has a pointer to the Transport, and many clients can point to the very same transport.

Comment: That is possible. But very unusual.

Comment: I would not call it unusual: If I instantiate many `Client`s without an explicit transport, the same `DefaultTransport` instance is shared amongst them.

Answer (score 0):

The consul-k8s project actually does this, by creating many short-lived Client instances, all sharing the same Transport. This was done in https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-k8s/commit/5672d344, perhaps accidentally as the [PR](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-k8s/pull/470) just said:

> Minor change to how we deal with consul clients in the endpoints controller+tests.

Prior to this minor change, it creates a new Transport every time (and thus leaks plenty of connections):

```
localConfig := api.DefaultConfig()
```

After the change, it reuses the same Transport:

```
localConfig := r.ConsulClientCfg
```

The leaky version never made it into any actual release, so it is all good.